# Angular Unit Tests using TestBed.inject succeed/fail according to tests execution order

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have an angular application (v11.1.0) using Jest for UnitTests.

I use `TestBed.inject` in order to get a service instance inside single tests and spyOn their methods to test or they have been called or mocking the return values.

However after switching to Typescript `strict` mode, the test fails. But if I change the order of some tests, everything runs smoothly.
It seems the mocked services still interacts between the different unit tests.

I tried to use `jest.resetAllMocks()`, but it does not solve the problem either. Below the code I use:

**Unit Test**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          RouterTestingModule,
          HttpClientTestingModule,
          TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        providers: [
          { provide: InformationService, useValue: informationServiceMock }
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

 describe('Test set', () => {
    it(`should have default text`, () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.maintenanceBannerMessage).toBe('BANNER DE');
      expect(component.maintenanceBannerTitle).toBe('TITLE DE');
    });

    it(`Should open function`, () => {
      const dialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
      const informationService = TestBed.inject(InformationService);
      jest.spyOn(informationService, 'updateOverlayAction');
      jest.spyOn(dialog, 'open');
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(informationService.updateOverlayAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // If I move this test in 2. position, the test `Should open function` FAILS
    // as getAnnouncementsByType keeps returning null instead of getting it from the
    // informationServiceMock provided in the configureTestingModule

    it(`should not be showed`, () => {
      const informationService = TestBed.inject(InformationService);
      jest
        .spyOn(informationService, 'getAnnouncementsByType')
        .mockReturnValue(of(null as any));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.maintenanceBannerMessage).toBeUndefined();
      expect(component.maintenanceBannerTitle).toBeUndefined();
    });
    //------------------------------------------------------------

    it(`should not be showed`, () => {
      const dialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
     const informationService = TestBed.inject(InformationService);
      jest
        .spyOn(informationService, 'getAnnouncementsByType')
        .mockReturnValue(of(null as any));
      jest.spyOn(dialog, 'open');
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(dialog.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

**Service Mock**

```
export const announcementsMockData = [
  {
    announcementId: '6000',
    type: AnnouncementType.BANNER,
    text: { de: 'BANNER DE', fr: 'BANNER FR', it: 'BANNER IT', en: 'BANNER EN' },
    title: { de: 'TITLE DE', fr: 'TITLE FR', it: 'TITLE IT', en: 'TITLE EN' }
  }, {
    announcementId: '6100',
    type: AnnouncementType.OVERLAY,
    text: { de: 'OVERLAY DE', fr: 'OVERLAY FR', it: 'OVERLAY IT', en: 'OVERLAY EN' },
    title: { de: 'OVERLAY DE', fr: 'OVERLAY FR', it: 'OVERLAY IT', en: 'OVERLAY EN' },
    _links: { create: { href: '/announcements/6100/actions' } }
  }
];

export const informationServiceMock = {
  getAnnouncementsByType: (type: AnnouncementType) => {
    return announcementsMockData.map(a => new Announcement(a)).filter(a => a.type === type);
  },
  updateOverlayAction: (link: ResourceLink, action: OverlayAction) => of(null),
};
```

**app component**

```
this.informationService.getAnnouncementsByType(AnnouncementType.BANNER)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe(([currentLanguage, banners]) => {
    if (banners?.length > 0) {
      if (banners[0].title) {
        this.maintenanceBannerTitle = banners[0].title[currentLanguage.key as keyof LanguageObject];
      }
      if (banners[0].text) {
        this.maintenanceBannerMessage =
          banners[0].text[currentLanguage.key as keyof LanguageObject];
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: It's unclear how it's related to TS strict. It doesn't affect how it works at runtime. Did you mean alwaysStrict?

Comment: I also don't think it is related. I mentioned it as I refactored the code adding `strict` mode and Angular strictTemplate checks. It seems something related to the mocked tests, as inverting the order they run through, hence it should not be related to the code itself, rather to the previous mocked values that keep persisted among tests

Comment: It's unclear at which point getAnnouncementsByType is called. `jest.resetAllMocks()` should be not just tried but be permanently used. Is the behaviour exactly the same with it? Move it to beforeEach or better enable it in Jest config.

Comment: In the 2. Test, I do not mock `getAnnouncementsByType` as I want to test the "happy path", hence the default value inside the app.component. This method is called in the component. However if I run the 3. Test before the 2., the `getAnnouncementsByType` return null in the component. As if the test would "remember" the previous mocked value that returns `null`.
Adding `jest.resetAllMocks()` in BeforeEach triggers an exception in the component in the `subscribe()` method as  the returned observable is undefined. Therefore I removed it for the time being.

Comment: I see. I pasted resetAllMocks without noticing.resetAllMocks should never be used in Jest, it's harmful. Use restoreAllMocks, etc instead. *As if the test would "remember" the previous mocked value that returns null* - it really does, that's why it's important to consistently restore mocks to original state before each test.

Comment: And that was it! If you write an answer, I will gladly accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test-specific spies should be restored to some implementation that is common for all tests, not doing this results in test cross contamination because a test affects subsequent tests.

`jest.resetAllMocks()` provides undesirable behaviour and should be avoided at all. When used in `beforeEach`, it resets the implementation of all spies with no exception and makes them stubs. When used in a test, this results in test cross contamination as well. In case specific spy implementation needs to be reset, this can be done with `mockReset()`.

As a rule of thumb, `jest.restoreAllMocks()` should be used in `beforeEach`, it restores all spies that were created with `jest.spyOn` to original implementation, in case there's any. This behaviour is generally desirable for all tests so it can be enabled in Jest configuration instead.